# Find and delete ends after one iteration

Tags: excel, vba

In Column A, I have the below values from 1 to 20.

```
1. NBC997
2. EVO463
3. EVO426
4. EVO420
5. EVO826
6. EVO820
7. EVO863
8. CRO001
9. BCA915
10. SBH121
11. KEN500
12. GAM201
13. GAM1011
14. GAM101
15. SPR577
16. SPR580
17. SPR579
18. SPR576
19. DON201
20. MOR101
```

My formula below should be looking at column A and deleting the entire row if the left 2 characters <> "EV".

Once it finds one iteration it stops and doesn't go to the next line.

```vb
Sub remove()

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 20
    If Left(Cells(i, "A"), 2) <> "EV" Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    Else
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: loop backwards `For i = 20 to 1 step -1`

Comment: You definitely need to loop backwards because the collection is re-indexed each time you remove a row. Still, that doesn't explain why your loop would apparently only execute once, so you may need further debugging...

Comment: Looping backwards makes sense!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the delete entire row. I would move the data up one row and then clear the contents of the last row.

```
Sub remove()
 Dim i As Long
 Dim x As Long
 Dim lastCol As Long
 Dim lastRow As Long
 Const dataColumn As Long = 1
 Const SearchPhrase As String = "EV"
 Const firstRow As Long = 1
 lastCol = Cells(firstRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, dataColumn).End(xlUp).Row
  x = 0
  For i = lastRow To firstRow Step -1

    If Left(Cells(i, dataColumn), Len(SearchPhrase)) <> SearchPhrase Then
       If i = lastRow Then
          Range(Cells(lastRow, dataColumn), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).ClearContents
       Else
          Range(Cells(i, dataColumn), Cells(lastRow - 1 - x, lastCol)).Value = _
          Range(Cells(i + 1, dataColumn), Cells(lastRow - x, lastCol)).Value
          Range(Cells(lastRow - x, dataColumn), Cells(lastRow - x, lastCol)).ClearContents
        End If
        x = x + 1
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This will technically work, but it's usually not considered a best practice to alter the iterator value. When deleting items from a collection, it's preferred to iterate backwards :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I do want to delete the line completely but its not a big issue. Your solution works, thank you very much.

Comment: Then just replace the right side of the range column with the number of comlumns with data and it will remove that row of data. cells(19-x,100) cells(20-x,100)

Comment: I adapted the code to adjust to what ever size of data you have and to incorporate the best practice of stepping up through the rows as David  suggested.